# как написать программу на питон используя словари

Tags: python, python-3.6

как написать проограмму на питоне реализуя словари? Программа эта проверяет оценку школьника по пятибальной шкале и взависимости от числа выявляет текст" плохо очень плохо и так далее"?

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {1: 'Очень плохо', 2: 'Плохо', 3: 'Удовлетворительно', 4: 'Хорошо', 5: 'Отлично'}
try:
    print(d[int(input('Введите балл > '))])
except ValueError:
    print('Введен неверный балл.')
except KeyError:
    print('Введен неверный балл.')
```